# Regex to extract text from request id

Tags: regex

i have a log where a certain part is requestid in that text is there which i have to extract

Ex: RES_1621480647_49610052479341623017223137119508459972977816017376903362_Book,

Can any1 pls help in extracting Book out of it

Comment: You will need to specify a bit more clearly which part you want to extract.  You've asked to extract "Book", which you can easily do with a regular expression but even easier with a simple text search.  Moreover, what have you tried so far?  Pretty much the first thing anyone learns about regular expressions is how to identify and extract simple groups of characters.  So, have you not yet got past the first stage of learning what regular expressions are?

Answer (score 0):

Consider string splitting instead

```py
>>> s = "RES_1621480647_49610052479341623017223137119508459972977816017376903362_Book"
>>> s.split("_")[-1]
'Book'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that string splitting will be more efficient, if you must use regular expressions, here is an example.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

print(
    re.findall(r"^\w+_\d+\d+_(\w+)$",'RES_1621480647_49610052479341623017223137119508459972977816017376903362_Book')
)

// output: ['Book']
```